# `cex.lab` Axis label exceeds plot region

Tags: r, graph

I want to create a plot with magnified axis labels using `cex.lab=2` but the label exceeds the plot region. Any ideas on how can I solve this?

Here is an example of the issue:

```
plot(1:10,1:10,ylab=~gamma,cex.lab=2)
```

Which produces a graph with a beheaded $\gamma$

[image]

I have done some search before asking the question both in google and in this site but my google foo betrayed me this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set larger margin of your plot window. That can be achieved with function `par()` and argument `mar=`. Numbers correspond to margin starting with bottom, then left margin, upper and right margin.

```
par(mar=c(5,5,1,1))
plot(1:10,1:10,ylab=~gamma,cex.lab=2)
```